# PHP mailer not working with client gmail id

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new in php i have a problem with my php mailer when i set

```
$Host = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$Username = 'my gamil id';
$Password = 'my gmail password';
$Port = 465;
```

Php mailer working fine, but when i change it to

```
$Host = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$Username = 'client gamil id';
$Password = 'client gmail password';
$Port = 465;
```

mailer not working and its shows an error message

> Authentication Required

I am from India and client from US, so is there any changes in configuration file?
Please help me

Here is my mailer.php file

```
include 'phpmailer/class.config.php';
include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
include 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
session_start();
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
if (MailConfig::$Debug) {
    $mail->Host = MailConfig::$DebugHost;
    $mail->Username = MailConfig::$DebugUsername;
    $mail->Password = MailConfig::$DebugPassword;
} else {
    $mail->Host = MailConfig::$Host;
    $mail->Username = MailConfig::$Username;
    $mail->Password = MailConfig::$Password;
}
$Subject = "Payment Received";

//////
/////////////
if (MailConfig::$Debug)
    $receipientEmail = "client@example.com";
else
    $receipientEmail = "client@example.com";


$Body = "A payment of $ " . $_POST['payment'] . " has been credited in your account";

        $mail->AddAddress($receipientEmail);
        $mail->Subject = $Subject;
        $mail->Body = $Body;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your PHP Mailer codes ?

Comment: Please check my php mailer code

Comment: if you find the answer useful, please click the "tick" sign to accept the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Host is incorrect . It should be:

```
$host = 'mail.gmail.com';
```

and the code is:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML();
$mail->IsSMTP();                           // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = MailConfig::$Host;     // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = MailConfig::$Username; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = MailConfig::$Password;
```

Note the `SMTPSecure` line